# Free command line archivers

Tags: windows, command-line, software-rec, archiving

Nowadays, we have a plethora of free arhivers (7-zip, j-zip, winrar <-- okey, that one's not free, ...)

But does anyone know of some free command line archivers for popular formats (RAR, ZIP or its unix variants) for Windows platform.

Comment: As Phoshi pointed out, 7-zip has a great command-line interface.  It really is becoming (has become?) the de facto standard in archiving tools.  Plus, a small part of me was so happy to notice the absence of WinZip in your list of examples.  ;)

Comment: I'll admit I prefer WinRAR for the GUI, but I do most of my stuff at the command line anyway, so 7z is invaluable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You said it! 7zip has a lovely CLI interface.

`p:\ath\to\7z.exe a hello.rar *.txt`

would archive all your text files in your current directory,

`p:\ath\to\7z.exe e hello.rar`

would recreate them.

Comment: better yet, drop it in your %systemroot% directory and do away with the ugly `p:\ath\to\` stuff. :)

Comment: That's very true - I have a fairly hacked together solution using python and doskey simply to avoid that stuff, but it's pretty damn good for one or twi things LD

Comment: Incredible. I've been using it forever, and never knew (nor bothered to check) whether it had a command line interface. Made my day, thanks !

Comment: It's not even a half-hearted interface, it's actually really bloody good! :)

Answer (score 1):

[GZIP for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gzip.htm) will definitely handle zipping / unzipping your "unix variants" on windows.

Comment: gzip in itself is not an arhiver (just compressor), need tar (or similar) as well for any archiving. But gzip is not the only way to compress a tar archive either so gzip is hardly enough.

Comment: True.  i got the impression from the wording of the question that perhaps @ldigas, was looking more for how to uncompress files in a 'unix format', but I think I read it too narrowly.

Answer (score 1):

winrar is very good (and it's free). Available on Windows and Linux and Mac

Comment: Where did you see it was free ?

Comment: The website has it as "trial". But you can use it as long as you don't mind clicking on "keep using" from time to time. You don't have to pay for it.

Comment: But you SHOULD pay for it.

Answer (score 0):

[Info-Zip](http://www.info-zip.org/) is great for zipping and unzipping zip-archives.